# How can I specify columns to plot on multiple files when using xmgrace?

Tags: xmgrace

I know that If I do:

```
xmgrace file1 file2 file2
```

There will be three sets of plots in different colors, and that if there are multiple columns in those files, the second the column will be plotted against the first.

What if I want plot the 3rd against the 1st for all of them?

I tried

```
xmgrace -block file1 file2 file2 -bxy 1:3
```

which doesn't work

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 6):

**Solution:**

It is necessary to specify the `-block` flag and the `-bxy col1:col2` flag/info for *each* file.

```
xmgrace -block file1 -bxy 1:3 -block file2 -bxy 1:3 -block file3 -bxy 1:3
```

**Explanation:**

From the xmgrace manual:

> ```
>  -block file
>           Assume the data file is block data
> ```

```
   -bxy x:y:etc.
          Form a set from the current block data set using the current set
          type from columns given in the argument
```

If you want to plot multiple sets of columns from the same file, you only need to use `-block` once, to specify the current block data set, then use `-bxy` to form data sets from the current block data set:

```
xmgrace -block file1 -bxy 1:3 -bxy 1:4 -bxy 1:5
```

For multiple files, like for what you are attempting, you must specify each file as the "current" block data set in sequence, and each time create new sets from the required columns using `-bxy n:m`.

It is more time-consuming to type, but follows logical progression from the *single data file* situation.

Comment: very useful indeed..!!